# Проблема с массивами, не могу понять

Tags: c, массивы, ввод

написала небольшой код, для "шифрования" введённого пользователем пароля, шифрованием это не назовёшь, это просто для себя.
В общем, я создала массив со значениями от 1 до 9 , я знаю , что нумерация массивов начинается с нуля. Так вот, на вход поступает пароль строго 4-х значный, допустим 1758 и вот как это я решила сделать:

```
int encrypt[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
                  1 7 5 8
//Введённый пароль пользователя
```

Смысл в том, что каждое число должно умножаться на элемент массива encrypt по порядку , слева направо, то-есть 1 * элемент массива 0 , что равно 1, потом 7 * элемент массива 1, что равно 2 и так далее до конца пароля.

Вот мой код:

```
int main()

{

int password[4];
int encrypt[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};


printf("Enter password:>\n");
scanf("%d",password);


printf("Your encrypted password:>\n");
    password[0]*encrypt[0];
    password[1]*encrypt[1];
    password[2]*encrypt[2];
    password[3]*encrypt[3];


    printf("%d %d %d  %d\n",password[0],password[1],password[2],password[3]);

  return 0;
  }
```

В результате , при введённом пароле 1758, он должен "зашифроваться" и вывестись как 1 14 15 32 (Результат умножения)

Но выводится первое значение массива password[0] и оно равно 1758, остальные 3 значения выводятся огромными цифрами, до меня не доходит , что нужно сделать, видимо пароль не записывается по отдельности, то-есть 1 в pasword[0], 7 в password[1], 5 в password[2], 8 в password[3], а это мне и надо, вместо этого выводится: 1758 4874240 -1074424516 4862675

Ввёдённый пароль 1758 это просто число, которое тупо записывается в password[0], но как можно каждую цифру по отдельности записывать.

Объясните, как нужно записать каждую цифру в массив password[4] , чтобы каждая цифра присваивалась в элемент массива

Comment: Чтобы разделить число на отдельные цифры, используйте операции остатка по модулю 10 и целочисленного деления 1758 % 10 = 8;   1758 / 10 = 175, снова модуль применить для выделения 5 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с конца.

```
password[0]*encrypt[0];
```

Вы умножаете, но при этом теряете результат умножения. Наверное, вы хотели

```
password[0] = password[0]*encrypt[0];
```

или, что то же самое

```
password[0] *= encrypt[0];
```

А теперь перейдем к началу.

```
scanf("%d",password);
```

Вот это - ерунда. В том плане, что все число полностью читается в `password[0]`, а не в четыре элемента...

Или используйте

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d",password,password+1,password+2,password+3);
```

если вводите четыре цифры с пробелами между ними, или, если вводите как единое число -

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
password[3] = n%10;  n /= 10;  
password[2] = n%10;  n /= 10;  
password[1] = n%10;  n /= 10;  
password[0] = n%10;
```

Ну, если, конечно, `n` - четырехзначное число...

Comment: Оу, я поняла, спасибо вам за помощь